# Nodejs. SyntaxError: Failed to parse JSON body: Unexpected end of input

Tags: node.js

I am not familiar with nodejs and js at all, but i need to understand what's wrong here.
When i'm trying to get some web pages i get exceptions like this.

```
Jan 16 10:35:17 ntw03 node[30441]: 01/16/2019 10:35:17 AM - error: 
REST Server Error: [SyntaxError: Failed to parse JSON body: Unexpected 
token v]
Jan 16 10:35:17 ntw03 node[30441]: at 
 APIServer.API.APIServer.retryMakeCall (/var/lib/contrail-webui/contrail-web-core/src/serverroot/common/rest.api.js:206:13)
Jan 16 10:35:17 ntw03 node[30441]: at Request.<anonymous> (/var/lib/contrail-webui/contrail-web-core/src/serverroot/common/rest.api.js:338:18)
Jan 16 10:35:17 ntw03 node[30441]: at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
Jan 16 10:35:17 ntw03 node[30441]: at Request.emit (events.js:172:7)
Jan 16 10:35:17 ntw03 node[30441]: at Request.mixin._fireError (/var/lib/contrail-webui/node_modules/restler/lib/restler.js:230:10)
Jan 16 10:35:17 ntw03 node[30441]: at /var/lib/contrail-webui/node_modules/restler/lib/restler.js:180:20
Jan 16 10:35:17 ntw03 node[30441]: at IncomingMessage.parsers.json (/var/lib/contrail-webui/node_modules/restler/lib/restler.js:426:9)
Jan 16 10:35:17 ntw03 node[30441]: at IncomingMessage.parsers.auto (/var/lib/contrail-webui/node_modules/restler/lib/restler.js:414:21)
Jan 16 10:35:17 ntw03 node[30441]: at Request.mixin._encode (/var/lib/contrail-webui/node_modules/restler/lib/restler.js:220:29)
Jan 16 10:35:17 ntw03 node[30441]: at /var/lib/contrail-webui/node_modules/restler/lib/restler.js:178:16
```

And another similar one

```
Error : [SyntaxError: Failed to parse JSON body: Unexpected end of input]
Full trace:
Jan 16 10:43:44 ntw03 node[30441]: SyntaxError: Failed to parse JSON body: Unexpected end of input
Jan 16 10:43:44 ntw03 node[30441]: at Object.parse (native)
Jan 16 10:43:44 ntw03 node[30441]: at IncomingMessage.parsers.json (/var/lib/contrail-webui/node_modules/restler/lib/restler.js:423:29)
Jan 16 10:43:44 ntw03 node[30441]: at IncomingMessage.parsers.auto (/var/lib/contrail-webui/node_modules/restler/lib/restler.js:414:21)
Jan 16 10:43:44 ntw03 node[30441]: at Request.mixin._encode (/var/lib/contrail-webui/node_modules/restler/lib/restler.js:220:29)
Jan 16 10:43:44 ntw03 node[30441]: at /var/lib/contrail-webui/node_modules/restler/lib/restler.js:178:16
Jan 16 10:43:44 ntw03 node[30441]: at Request.mixin._decode (/var/lib/contrail-webui/node_modules/restler/lib/restler.js:194:7)
Jan 16 10:43:44 ntw03 node[30441]: at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/var/lib/contrail-webui/node_modules/restler/lib/restler.js:171:14)
Jan 16 10:43:44 ntw03 node[30441]: at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
Jan 16 10:43:44 ntw03 node[30441]: at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:166:7)
Jan 16 10:43:44 ntw03 node[30441]: at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:905:12)
Jan 16 10:43:44 ntw03 node[30441]: 01/16/2019 10:43:44 AM - error: URL [http://172.17.96.150:8082/] returned error [{}]
Jan 16 10:43:44 ntw03 node[30441]: 01/16/2019 10:43:44 AM - error: REST Server Error: [SyntaxError: Failed to parse JSON body: Unexpected end of input]
Jan 16 10:43:44 ntw03 node[30441]: at APIServer.API.APIServer.retryMakeCall (/var/lib/contrail-webui/contrail-web-core/src/serverroot/common/rest.api.js:206:13)
Jan 16 10:43:44 ntw03 node[30441]: at Request.<anonymous> (/var/lib/contrail-webui/contrail-web-core/src/serverroot/common/rest.api.js:338:18)
Jan 16 10:43:44 ntw03 node[30441]: at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
Jan 16 10:43:44 ntw03 node[30441]: at Request.emit (events.js:172:7)
Jan 16 10:43:44 ntw03 node[30441]: at Request.mixin._fireError (/var/lib/contrail-webui/node_modules/restler/lib/restler.js:230:10)
Jan 16 10:43:44 ntw03 node[30441]: at /var/lib/contrail-webui/node_modules/restler/lib/restler.js:180:20
Jan 16 10:43:44 ntw03 node[30441]: at IncomingMessage.parsers.json (/var/lib/contrail-webui/node_modules/restler/lib/restler.js:426:9)
Jan 16 10:43:44 ntw03 node[30441]: at IncomingMessage.parsers.auto (/var/lib/contrail-webui/node_modules/restler/lib/restler.js:414:21)
Jan 16 10:43:44 ntw03 node[30441]: at Request.mixin._encode (/var/lib/contrail-webui/node_modules/restler/lib/restler.js:220:29)
Jan 16 10:43:44 ntw03 node[30441]: at /var/lib/contrail-webui/node_modules/restler/lib/restler.js:178:16
```

Version of nodejs 4.2.6, restler lib 3.1.0

This is link to source REST request - 
https://github.com/Juniper/contrail-web-core/blob/R4.1/src/serverroot/common/rest.api.js#L252

Guys from contrail didn't anwser to me, so i want to ask help from node js  experts.

Comment: can you paste your code?

Comment: What are you trying to do? An HTTP call that replies with a JSON?

Comment: Source code  - https://github.com/Juniper/contrail-web-core/blob/R4.1/src/serverroot/common/rest.api.js#L252
I am trying to do HTTP call that replies with JSON, yes.

Comment: Issue was related to HAproxy settings.